# How to overwrite(?) a jQuery event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been working on this for like days now, and I still just can't figure it out.

I built a slide-out menu with jQuery, and it works. The thing is, I want the menu button that opens it to also be the button that closes it.

What I have done is set the menu button to have the class '.inactive' by default, theb set up a click event handler to open the menu, then remove the '.inactive' class from the element and add the class '.active'. Then I made another function doing the opposite of that.
The problem is, the first event works perfectly, but the second event doesn't. The menu opens and jQuery edits the HTML's style, but when I click the button again, the styles won't change.

Is there a way to overwrite the first event so that the second event can be executed?
Sorry if this has a really basic solution that I'm missing, but here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.inactive').click(function() {
        do_animations();
        //'.menu-button i' below is the menu button which gets the active/inactive classes//
        $('.menu-button i').addClass('active');
        $('.menu-button i').removeClass('inactive');
    });

    $('.active').click(function() {
        do_animations();
        $('.menu-button i').addClass('inactive');
        $('.menu-button i').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

I can provide all the details of the code if you need them, but those are the important parts, so as not to make this too long. I'm certain all the syntax is right and I'm not getting any errors in the developer tools.

Comment: You are missing the fact that events are bound to elements, not css selections. Changing an element's class won't change what events are bound to it.

Comment: Have you tried with $('.inactive').on('click, , function() { ...}); and $('.active').on('click, , function() { ...}); instead?

Comment: Kevin, in that case, what about the code should change?

Comment: Splendonia, I just tried that but unfortunately it's still doing the same thing as before.

Comment: How have you verified that the second click is not registered? both run do_animations(). Is it possible that you are executing the script but there are no noticeable changes in the UI? Could you post a fiddle or give us the contents of do_animations? any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use event delegation here. Something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //body will work but preferably the container of these elements would be best
    $('body').on('click', '.inactive', function() {
        do_animations();
        //'.menu-button i' below is the menu button which gets the active/inactive classes//
        $('.menu-button i').addClass('active');
        $('.menu-button i').removeClass('inactive');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.active', function() {
        do_animations();
        $('.menu-button i').addClass('inactive');
        $('.menu-button i').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

This works by saying: When the body is clicked anywhere. Check to see if the element had the class .inactive if so call the function.

The previous solution worked by saying: find all of the elements in the page and register this callback on them. Thus when it searched for elements with the .active tag and found none. it registered no callbacks.

Comment: YES that worked! Thanks for explaining why that works, I'll keep that in mind for next time. Thank you very much!